# Cannot retrieving the expanded_url - twitteroauth / twitter api

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Cannot get the **expanded_url** from this tweet -> https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1297715123360915457,
but it works fine here -> https://twitter.com/i/web/status/1298033841374822400

I'm using **[abraham/twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)** version 1.2.0, also tried on 1.1.0 and 2.0.1.
Still not retrieving the **expanded_url**.

```
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$connection = new TwitterOAuth(
    TW_KEY,
    TW_SECRET,
    TW_TOKEN,
    TW_TOKEN_SECRET
);

$tweetResult = $connection->get(
  "statuses/show",
  [
    'id'    => '1298033841374822400', "tweet_mode" => "extended"
    //'id'    => '1297715123360915457', "tweet_mode" => "extended"
  ]
);
var_dump($tweetResult->entities->urls);
```

result for **1298033841374822400**:

```
array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#11 (4) { ["url"]=> string(23) "the short URL" ["expanded_url"]=> string(53) "https://contest.mdpr.jp/mrcon202003/gal/taiki06191148" ["display_url"]=> string(33) "contest.mdpr.jp/mrcon202003/ga…" ["indices"]=> array(2) { [0]=> int(67) [1]=> int(90) } } }
```

and result for **1297715123360915457**

```
array(0) { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second Tweet is a retweet, so the urls are at

`$tweetResult->retweeted_status->entities->urls`

Comment: both of them are retweets, thank you so much, it does work perfectly.